# Can I refer another namespace and expose its functions as public for the current ns?

Tags: namespaces, clojure

I thought `use` would do it but it seems the mapping created in the current namespace is not public. Here is an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
(ns my-ns
  (:use [another-ns :only (another-fct)]))

(defn my-fct
  []
  (another-fct 123)) ; this works fine
```

Then I have another namespace like this:

```
(ns my-ns-2
   (:require [my-ns :as my]))

(defn my-fct-2
  []
  (my/another-fct 456)) ; this doesn't work
```

I would like to do that because `another-ns` is a library to access a database. I would like to isolate all the calls to this library in a single namespace (`my-ns`), this way all the DB dependent functions would be isolated in a single namespace and it becomes easier to switch to another DB if needed.

Some of the functions of this library are just fine for me but I'd like to augment others. Let's say the read functions are fine but I'd like to augment the write functions with some validation.

The only way I see so far is to hand-code all the mapping into `my-ns` even for the functions I don't augment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this help?

```
(defmacro pull [ns vlist]
  `(do ~@(for [i vlist]
           `(def ~i ~(symbol (str ns "/" i))))))
```

Here's an example:

```
(ns my-ns)

(defmacro pull [ns vlist]
  `(do ~@(for [i vlist]
           `(def ~i ~(symbol (str ns "/" i))))))

(pull clojure.string (reverse replace))

(defn my-reverse
  []
  (reverse "abc"))

(ns my-ns-2)

(defn my-fct-2 []
  (list (my-ns/my-reverse)
        (my-ns/reverse "abc")))

(my-fct-2)
```

If you want to just pull in everything, then:

```
(defmacro pullall [ns]
  `(do ~@(for [i (map first (ns-publics ns))]
           `(def ~i ~(symbol (str ns "/" i))))))

(pullall clojure.string)
```

Comment: Hmm. Useful, but appears to be limited to namespaces that contain functions alone: `Can't take the value of a macro`.

Answer (score 12):

One way to do this selectively (specifying each function explicitly) is to use something like Zach Tellman's [Potemkin library](https://github.com/ztellman/potemkin/blob/master/src/potemkin.clj).  An example of it's use is found in the [lamina.core](https://github.com/ztellman/lamina/blob/master/src/lamina/core.clj) namespace which serves as the public entry point for Lamina, importing the key public functions from all other internal namespaces.

You can also use [clojure.contrib.def/defalias](http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/def-api.html#clojure.contrib.def/defalias):

```
(use 'clojure.contrib.def/defalias)
(defalias foo clojure.string/blank?)
(foo "")
```

Comment: Potemkin is awesome. I found this more helpful than the accepted answer, which doesn't work on macros.

Comment: `defalias` was [not truly an alias but a copy](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/LhidPSlvX_Q/mS4R_52suXwJ)

Answer (score 1):

To pull everything from namespace that may have macros defined within use this

```
(defmacro pullall [ns]
  `(do ~@(for [[sym var] (ns-publics ns)]
           `(def ~sym ~var))))
```