# Clojure: re-export vars

Tags: namespaces, clojure

Is there a way to re-export some namespace's vars from another namespace? I'd like to be able to do this:

```
(ns mine.core
  (:use [incanter core charts datasets io]))

; re-export Incanter somehow
```

Then in the REPL I would be able to use Incanter's functions by just `use`-ing `mine.core`.

```
user=> (use 'mine.core)
nil
user=> (view (histogram (sample-normal 1000)))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732134/can-i-refer-another-namespace-and-expose-its-functions-as-public-for-the-current?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I used to accomplish this by putting the commonly REPLd `use` expressions in a separate file that I can `load-file` when I start my REPL. This worked fairly well because I could put everything in there and then get at more than just one namespace.

Later I switched to defining an 'everything' namespace and starting my repl in that using leiningend `:main` directive [like in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306157/to-start-repl-in-user-defined-namespace) which was like my first approach but seemed more elegant.

my ways continued to change and i now always **switch to the namespace containing the code**. This has worked well because on larger project It helps keep track of what code goes where and I think this practice helps me learn the layout of the code faster. Of course everyone's experiences are different and personal, YMMV :)

Answer (score 1):

Try http://code.google.com/p/clj-nstools/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to consider importing all necessary dependencies explicitly as suggested in other answers. This usually leads to less complex code.

However if you do want this, e.g. to present a consistent interface, then you can do this with `clojure.core/intern` function that makes any symbol "native" to given namespace. For example:

```clj
(ns user)
(intern 'user 'map clojure.core/map)    
(ns new-ns)
(require 'user)
(user/map inc [1 2 3])
; => [2 3 4]    
(use 'user)
; =>  WARNING: map already refers to: #'clojure.core/map in namespace: new-ns, 
;     being replaced by: #'user/map
(map inc [1 2 3]) 
; => [2 3 4]
```

Note that changes in symbol's original namespace will not be reflected until you re-intern the symbol.