# How do I duplicate a namespace in clojurescript?

Tags: namespaces, clojurescript

I would like to copy - or create an alias for - the module `other.thing` in clojurescript.

Obviously, I can create a file `thing` in the library `my`:

```
(ns my.thing
  (:require 
    [other.thing]))
(def a other.thing/a)
(def b other.thing/b)
(def c other.thing/c)
...
```

But this is rather verbose.
It would be nice to:

- be able to re-export without naming each item by hand
- do so without using a separate file

What other options are available?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is unidiomatic to do that. In the answers of [this releated SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954153/clojure-re-export-vars), people are recommending importing explicitly the required namespaces when using them. There's also this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/k8el4v/cljs_reexport_intern_analogue/) where a redditor has created a tool for re-exporting namespaces, but you still have to do it manually for every function.